# Jquery - Click to copy parent element to text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, copy

I want 4 buttons next to each URL, you can then click on a button to copy the parent url to the buttons respective textfield.

I presume that it is easiest to do this using jquery but I have no clue where to start. Any advice would be much appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/WwdMw/

```
<div class="selection">
  <div class"url">
    <h2>example1.com</h2>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt1">Copy to Option1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt2">Copy to Option2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt3">Copy to Option3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt4">Copy to Option4</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="selection">
  <div class"url">
    <h2>example3.com</h2>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt1">Copy to Option1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt2">Copy to Option2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt3">Copy to Option3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt4">Copy to Option4</button>
</div>
<hr/>

<div class="selection">
  <div class"url">
    <h2>example2.com</h2>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt1">Copy to Option1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt2">Copy to Option2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt3">Copy to Option3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_opt4">Copy to Option4</button>
</div>

<hr/>
```

Comment: Can we see some JQuery code that you attempted?

Comment: This a relatively basic problem. While Rex did provide a fully working solution, I suggest to visit [http://learn.jquery.com/](http://learn.jquery.com/) so that you can actually learn _why_ and _how_ his code works, and not just accept that it does.

Comment: @ssell Yups you are right bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Have it.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var value = $(this).parent().find('h2').text();
    var idIdentifier = $(this).text().substr($(this).text().length - 1);
    var textArea = $('div[class*='+idIdentifier+']').find('textarea');
    textArea.val(textArea.val() +" "+ value);
})
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WwdMw/4/)